# Percentage of total purchase for qualifying customers per date period

Tags: sql, netsuite, domo

I need to find the percentage of chocolate sold of customers which have purchased chocolate by month.
Take for example the below example table with only a single Month entry:

```
Cust_Id     Customer    Quantity    Item        Amount in $     Date         Month and year
1           Maria       2           chocolate   10                 01/01/2020   1-2020
1           Maria       1           banana      5                  01/01/2020   1-2020
1           Maria       3           cookies     3                  01/01/2020   1-2020
2           Carlos      5           cookies     10                 01/01/2020   1-2020
2           Carlos      3           banana      3                  01/01/2020   1-2020
3           Jose        1           banana      5                  01/01/2020   1-2020
3           Jose        1           chocolate   3                  01/01/2020   1-2020
4           Anne        10          chocolate   20                 01/01/2020   1-2020
4           Anne        1           banana      5                  01/01/2020   1-2020
4           Anne        10          cookies     15                 01/01/2020   1-2020
```

Of those customers that have purchased chocolate in January 2020 (Maria, Jose, and Anne, but **NOT** Carlos), how much of the total purchase (in %) was for chocolate?

A solution via pivot table in excel:

```
Month   1 2020
Customer Name   SUM of Amount in $  Total amount of purchase    Overall %
Anne            20                  40  
Jose            3                   8   
Maria           10                  18  
Grand Total     33                  66                         50.00%
```

The solution for date '1-2020' is **50%**

How can I determine the percentage of Chocolates sold per date period for only the customers that have purchased chocolate in that date period via SQL?

```
mysql> select * from orders where date = '1-2020';
+----------+-------------+---------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
| order_id | customer_id | customer_name | quantity | item      | amount | date   |
+----------+-------------+---------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
|        1 |           1 | Maria         |        2 | chocolate |     10 | 1-2020 |
|        2 |           1 | Maria         |        1 | banana    |      5 | 1-2020 |
|        3 |           1 | Maria         |        3 | cookies   |      3 | 1-2020 |
|        4 |           2 | Carlos        |        5 | cookies   |     10 | 1-2020 |
|        5 |           2 | Carlos        |        3 | banana    |      3 | 1-2020 |
|        6 |           3 | Jose          |        1 | banana    |      5 | 1-2020 |
|        7 |           3 | Jose          |        1 | chocolate |      3 | 1-2020 |
|        8 |           4 | Anne          |       10 | chocolate |     20 | 1-2020 |
|        9 |           4 | Anne          |        1 | banana    |      5 | 1-2020 |
|       10 |           4 | Anne          |       10 | cookies   |     15 | 1-2020 |
+----------+-------------+---------------+----------+-----------+--------+--------+
10 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The below query is ALMOST correct, only that it shows the total of $79 for January, when the correct amount is $66 (Carlos did not buy chocolate in January)

```
mysql> select date,     sum(case when item = 'chocolate' then amount end) as chocolate_amount,     sum(amount) as total_amount,     (sum(case when item = 'chocolate' then amount end) / sum(amount)) as percentage from orders where date = '1-2020' group by date having sum(case when item = 'chocolate' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
+--------+------------------+--------------+------------+
| date   | chocolate_amount | total_amount | percentage |
+--------+------------------+--------------+------------+
| 1-2020 |               33 |           79 |     0.4177 |
+--------+------------------+--------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Again, the correct calculation here would be **33 / 66 = 50%**
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select customer, 
       sum(case when item = 'chocolate' then amount end) as chocolate_amount,
       sum(amount) as total_amount,
       (sum(case when item = 'chocolate' then amount end) /
        sum(amount)
       ) as chocolate_ratio
from t
where date >= '2020-01-01' and date < '2020-02-01'
group by customer
having sum(case when item = 'chocolate' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: Thank you, will this work when the table has many many fiscal quarters?

Comment: Also, I need to find the overall percentage ratio, which is 50% for the month of January

Comment: Thank you @Gordon Linoff, the query is ALMOST giving me what I want, except that the total_amount here includes the customers which have not purchased chocolate per period. I have edited the post and added an example. Would you be able to have another look please? Thank you

Comment: @mmenschig . . . I don't understand your issue.  If the customer has not purchased chocolate, then the customer should be filtered out via the `having` clause.

Comment: I've added an answer below that is built on top of what you've provided. Thank you, it was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Gordon Linoff, I was able to modify his query to give me the result I needed. While not 100% correct, his query set me on the right path.

For anyone wondering what the query and result was:

**Query**

```
select o.date,
    sum(case when item = 'chocolate' then amount end) as chocolate_amount,
    t2.total_purchases,
    (sum(case when item = 'chocolate' then amount end) / t2.total_purchases) as percentage
from orders o
join (
    select date, sum(amount) as total_purchases
        from orders o1
        join (
            select distinct date, customer_id 
            from orders o2
            where item = 'chocolate'
        ) as chocolate_customers
using (date)
where o1.customer_id in (chocolate_customers.customer_id)
group by 1
) as t2 using (date)
group by date
having sum(case when item = 'chocolate' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

**Result**

```
+--------+------------------+-----------------+------------+
| date   | chocolate_amount | total_purchases | percentage |
+--------+------------------+-----------------+------------+
| 1-2020 |               33 |              66 |     0.5000 |
| 2-2020 |               10 |              15 |     0.6667 |
| 3-2020 |               55 |              62 |     0.8871 |
+--------+------------------+-----------------+------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks again